# Disable tab freezing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a web page, where the user can click a button, which will then open another tab with a somewhat limited version of what the main page is showing. The point of this is that this tab can be shared to another screen or via Teams/Zoom etc. Basically a lite version that only contains what other users are supposed to see.

As far as I can know, there are no issues if the main user shares it to another screen, i.e. another monitor, projector etc. However, if you are using e.g. Teams, and only have one screen, and then want to share this one tab for all to see, well, it freezes at some point. So any DOM updates to this screen will not happen until that tab is focused again. So basically the tab doesn't really work as intended, since the stuff the main user does on his/her screen should be shown on the lite/shared version of the page.

My question is therefore: Is there some way, without having each user disabling this freeze mode, to keep a certain page activated so that it won't go into freeze mode ?